# Again edit of edited UIImage in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiimage

In my iOS app, I am putting several UIImages on one back UIImage and then saving the overall back image with all subimages added on it by taking screenshot programmatically.

Now I want to change the subviews UIImages position of that saved image. So want to know how to detect the subview images position as I have taken whole image as screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Record their frame as converted to window coordinates. The pixels of the image should be the same as the frame origin (for normal) or double for retina. The screenshot is of the whole screen, so its dimensions are equivalent to the window frame. UIView has some convenience methods to convert arbitrary view frames to other view (or window) coordinates.

EDIT: to deal with content fit, you have to do the math yourself. You know the frame of the imageView, and you can ask the image for its size. Knowing the aspect ratio of each will let you determine in which dimension the image completely fits, and then you can compute the other dimension (which will be a value less than the imageView frame. Divide the difference of the view dimension minus the image dimension by two, and that lets you know the offset to the image inside the view. Now you can save the frame of the image as its displayed in the view.

Comment: Can you please explain with some example..because the image of UIImageView subview have property AspectRatioFit so its also lil bit tricky..Thanks